# how to calculate sum in django python

Tags: python, django, sum

I have 4 tables;
task and sub_task have resources and sub_task foreign key in another table c

This is the task table and subtask foreign key

```
class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    task = models.ForeignKey("self", on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                         related_name="subtasks", blank=True, null=True)
```

this is the "Resource" table

```
class Resource(models.Model):
    qty = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    rate = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    task = models.ForeignKey("Task", on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                             related_name="resources",  null=True)
    project = models.ForeignKey("Project", on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                related_name="resource")
```

Another table "Complete"

```
class Complete(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(
        "Task", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="d",
        blank=True)
    percentage = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
```

The complete table contains percentage complete and I need to calculate percentage complete in amount and remaining percentage in amount that will calculate from resources.
Each resource amount will calculate (rate * qty) from the resource table how to perform this operation in Django ORM

Can I provide some data?

Answer (score 0):

In your Complete table, you should make percentage, a property field, and then in the method you can use your related field to calculate the percentage.

```
    @property
    def percentage(self):
        # here you can get the related field's data using self
        return value
```